# Elliptic regularity at boundary

Tags: boundary-value-problem, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-operators

Suppose I have a (non-smooth) domain $\Omega$ on which I have a $H^1$ solution $u$ of a constant coefficient elliptic PDE $L$. Suppose also that $\Gamma$ is a smooth portion of the boundary $\partial\Omega$ and on a neighborhood of $\Gamma$ I prescribe Robin boundary conditions
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+bu=g
$$
where $a,b$ are constants (not both zero but $a=0$ corresponds to Dirichlet BCs and $b=0$ to Neumann BCs) and $g$ is some function. My question is, given some sort of regularity of $g$, can we say anything about regularity of $u$ up to the boundary? So far, everything I can find deals only with the Dirichlet case. Anyone know any references for the general case?

Comment: If your problem has a unique solution, then that solution has a trace on the boundary and that gives you Dirichlet boundary values. Otherwise, many regularity results seem to be part of the folklore, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Suppose I do have a unique solution and $g$ above is smooth. In the general case I am not quite sure how to use the Dirichlet results to get regularity in this case?

Comment: Such results might only be in the folklore, in which case you'll have to do it by yourself. One vaguely related keyword is "Zaremba problem"; those have both Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions but on different parts of the boundary, so not what you are looking for. If you have your literature search and could not find anything, than folklore it probably is.